# tmux window won't resize, and persistant 80x24 client

Tags: putty, tmux, byobu

Connected to my box via Putty.exe

```
$ tmux list-clients
/dev/pts/2: 1 [80x24 xterm-256color] (utf8)                                     
/dev/pts/9: 1 [94x30 linux] (utf8) 

$ tmux detach-client -t /dev/pts/2
```

the terminal flashes resizing the window to the full 94x30 for a moment
and then immediately resizes it back to 80x24

```
$ tmux list-clients
/dev/pts/2: 1 [80x24 xterm-256color] (utf8)                                     
/dev/pts/9: 1 [94x30 linux] (utf8)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to disconnect the remote client, which is attached using a smaller window.  You may be able to use the [Byobu](http://byobu.org) hot-key <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>, or run `/usr/lib/byobu/include/tmux-detach-all-but-current-client`

Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.org).

Comment: I tried that repeatedly and it didn't work. I ended up upgrading to the latest tmux and that resolved it.